# After update, emails have to be written out in full html!

Tags: civimail, email, upgrade, ckeditor

We updated CiviCRM and the next time I tried to email a contact, I found all the buttons to insert bold, hyperlinks etc. had disappeared and the only option seemed to type it all in manually, even including the `<p> </p>` at beginning and end of paragraphs! Same thing when I looked at the mass mailing function. Is this a bug, deliberate, or some weird problem that only we have?
Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to CiviCRM SE. You need to give a bit more information about your situation. Which versions are you updating from and to? Also probably relevant which CMS you are using. Looks like something is wrong with access to the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Also worth looking for similar problems before posting a new query. Try searching for CKEditor (which is the WYSIWYG editor)

Answer (score 1):

Using WordPress I had a problem where CiviCRM was installed on a subdomain and I to do a workround. See [WYSIWYG editor not present with WordPress](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20888/wysiwyg-editor-not-present-with-wordpress). This has to be redone when you upgrade. So possibly this is a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance that you have the extension "Grant Applications" enabled? I had a similar issue and found a conflict with this extension.