# CKEditor not visible

Tags: wordpress, ckeditor

I'm struggling to get the CKeditor to work on civimail - there is a blank space above the text box space. I've made sure CKEditor is selected in Administer > Customise data and screens > Display preferences.

Has anyone got anything similar or a solution?

Edit: We are using version 5.4.1, on wordpress 4.7.5

Comment: pls update your Q with version etc

Comment: Hi, sorry - done!

Answer (score 2):

Is your CiviCRM in a subdomain of the main WordPress site? If so it looks like the problem I had a while back. See [WYSIWYG editor not present with WordPress](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20888/wysiwyg-editor-not-present-with-wordpress/21295#21295) for the details and my work around.