# CKEditor does not display when editing event

Tags: ckeditor

I just upgraded to civicrm 5.12.0 and the ckeditor is not available when editing an event. It is there when entering a new event. I think we had this problem with the previous version as well.

Comment: check if you have paths and  resource url configured correctly at `Admin->system settings -> directories` and `Admin->system settings->resource url`

Comment: No the CKEditor works when entering an event and in entering and editing in civimail, but disappears only when trying to edit an event.

Answer (score 2):

My solution to my own earlier question: [WYSIWYG editor not present with WordPress](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20888/wysiwyg-editor-not-present-with-wordpress) may provide an answer. If this was the cause of your previous problem it would have reverted on an upgrade.

Is CKEditor missing in all circumstances (eg sending an email)?